# Unable to add CSV files as a hosted feature layer in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have a hosted feature layers of 2 geometry types.

1. Geometry Type - Point
2. Geometry Type - Polyline

I want to export these layers and import it on another map.

I used the following steps:

1. Exported these hosted feature layers as a CSV file.
2. Opened map and click on "Add" button and selected Add layer from file option then I selected downloaded CSV file.

I am getting the following error:

1. For Point type

   [image: point type]
2. For Polyline type

   [image: polyline type]

I have uploaded the downloaded CSV file on drive
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OY5uxHsvuL1JnzmaeL5p5Yv6fgIy7fsI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing your geometry from your CSV.

[image]

i was able to map your x,y in standard wgs 1984 but i am not sure what scale to use so that you can see your points with imagery.

[image]

regardless, your points file has geometry so you should be able to get it working in arcmap and then reshare to your arcgis online account but your polyline file does not have geometry and thats why you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple issues here. Check the documentation on uploading CSVs to ArcGIS Online - [CSV, TXT, and GPX files - ArcGIS Online Help](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/csv-gpx.htm).

For the files you linked:

- `Polyline.csv` - Doesn't appear to have any geometry.
- `points.csv` - Assuming the x2 and y2 fields are Lat/Lng, you should be prompted to choose the location fields for the feature service when you upload the file. Since you also have x and y fields though, it will default to those.
  [image: CSV upload dialog]